# "Group" Datatype, group_concat without a "group"

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

For `group_concat` the [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) manual says:

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group.

`group` in this context seems like it is a datatype of some sort. Is it possible to create this data type manually?

An example, I have `one` and `two` in a table and I want to retrieve those two values separated as a CSV:

```
select group_concat(column) from table group by column
```

This concatenates

```
'one', 'two'
```

as expected, however:

```
select group_concat('one', 'two');
```

returns:

`'onetwo'`

as if it were just `concat`.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT it’s similar to CONCAT, but it differs in the way that CONCAT is used to combine values across columns, while the GROUP_CONCAT function is mostly used for concatenating values across rows.

Comment: `concat` concats without separator, it works with more than just columns. e.g. `concat('some string', some_column, 'another string', 123)`. The "rows" portion is what I'm trying to emulate. e.g. in PHP I could do `[['row1', 'field2'], ['row2', 'field2']]` which would achieve a similar result set (missing indices but for demo think it works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group is not a data type. In this context, it refers to a set of rows, defined by the rows with the same value in the column you name in the `GROUP BY` clause.

GROUP_CONCAT() with multiple arguments acts like CONCAT(), as mentioned in the comments above. That is, multiple arguments are concatenated into a single string.

You seem to want to concatenate multiple arguments with a comma separator, without taking the values from a set of rows. For this, you could use MySQL's string function [CONCAT_WS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
select concat_ws(',', 'one', 'two') as my_list;

+---------+
| my_list |
+---------+
| one,two |
+---------+
```